# Hiding data inside an mp3 file

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, steganography

I am currently working on a project to hide data inside an mp3 file...What I did was, I replaced the last BYTE of every mp3 frame with the bytes from message file(the file to be hidden)... It works fine... I could hide the file in it and also successfully extract it... But some noise are present in the resulting mp3 file, due to addition of external data which is, definitely, not desired... Please help me in where to store the data in mp3 so as to reduce the noise...

PS: There is already a tool to use mp3 for hiding data -Mp3Stego. But it takes uncompressed wav file as input. But I need to have mp3 as input.

Comment: Why don't decompress the input file to a wav then use Mp3Stego ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Guillaume. But I'm trying to use mp3 file as such... And moreover mp3Stego can hide only text... I'm trying to develop a system that can hide any file inside mp3... And anyway.. Thanks for your concern, I really appreciate that....

Answer (score 1):

Such kind of tools do not replace whole byte. They are replace only last BIT. Try to replace only a BIT instead of BYTE. This will reduce the noise, but also reduce size of an information which you can put in file.